# (Minecraft Spigot API 1.16.5) Bypass clicking on hitbox (transferring hit to a different mob)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on a Minecraft spigot mini-game where players boat around and try and blow up the creepers in the back of thier opponent's boat. However, it is far too difficult to actually click on a creeper in the back of a boat. For that reason, I am currently summoning an invisible mob in order to allow for a larger hitbox. The problem is players cannot click the opposing hitbox because the hitbox of the larger mob in thier boat is blocking thier click. I am hoping someone has some ideas on how to do this, or other methods to make the minigame functional.

Thank you in advance and check the image so you know what I am working with.
[Minigame test arena with visual of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9YEA.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the player attacks an entity, the entity ID which the client attacks is sent in a packet to the server. You can check if the id of the attacked entity is the "hitbox-entity" of your real entity which should be attacked, and change the packet data which will be processed by the server. You can do this with ProtocolLib.